# Spatial Join for Batch Processing

Tags: arcpy, shapefile, spatial-join, batch, error-000732

I want to run the spatial join tool to join hundreds of shapefiles from two different folders.

---

For example one folder contains point  shapefiles with names d1.1,d1.2,d1.3  . . . .

the other folder contain shapefiles with names q1.1,q1.2,q1.3  . . . .

i want to join d1.1 to q1.1, d1.2 to q1.2  and so on, using python but getting the error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):

  File "C:\spatial join.py", line 28, in <module>

    arcpy.SpatialJoin_analysis(tarf, joinf, output, "JOIN_ONE_TO_ONE", 

"KEEP_ALL", "POINTID \"POINTID\" true true false 6 Long 0 6 ,First,#,fc[:-
4],POINTID,-1,-1;AOD \"AOD\" true true false 10 Long 0 10 ,First,#,fc[:-4],GRID_CODE,-1,-1;QF \"QF\" true true false 10 Long 0 10 ,First,#,fs[:-4],GRID_CODE,-1,-1", "INTERSECT", "", "")

  File "C:\Program Files (x86)\ArcGIS\Desktop10.3\ArcPy\arcpy\analysis.py", line 471, in SpatialJoin
    raise e

ExecuteError: Failed to execute. Parameters are not valid.

ERROR 000732: Target Features: Dataset da2016001.0510 does not exist or is not supported

ERROR 000732: Join Features: Dataset qfa2016001.0510 does not exist or is not supported

Failed to execute (SpatialJoin).
```

Here is my code

```
import arcpy

arcpy.env.workspace = r"C:\pointsD"

fcsD = arcpy.ListFeatureClasses()

arcpy.env.workspace = r"C:\pointsQF"

fcsQF = arcpy.ListFeatureClasses()

for fc in fcsD:

    for fs in fcsQF:

        if fs[3:]== fc[2:]:

            tarf = fc[:-4]

            joinf = fs[:-4]

            output = r"C:\DWithQF" + fc[1:-4]

            # Process: Spatial Join

            arcpy.SpatialJoin_analysis(tarf, joinf, output, "JOIN_ONE_TO_ONE", 
"KEEP_ALL", "POINTID \"POINTID\" true true false 6 Long 0 6 ,First,#,fc[:-4],POINTID,-1,-1;AOD \"AOD\" true true false 10 Long 0 10 ,First,#,fc[:-4],GRID_CODE,-1,-1;QF \"QF\" true true false 10 Long 0 10 ,First,#,fs[:-4],GRID_CODE,-1,-1", "INTERSECT", "", "")

print "Done"
```

Comment: You probably need to add the Path "C:\pointsD" to tarf variable because your Workspace is still set to the QF workspace.